# difference in xamarin vs java documentation for ECPublicKey

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, ecdsa

in andorid xamarin project I am generating key pair using EC curves

```
generator = KeyPairGenerator.GetInstance(KeyProperties.KeyAlgorithmEc, AndroidKeyStoreContants.AndroidKeyStore);

            paramSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    alias,
                    KeyStorePurpose.Sign | KeyStorePurpose.Verify)
                        .SetAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                        .SetDigests(KeyProperties.DigestSha256)
                        .Build();

            generator.Initialize(paramSpec);


            var keyPair = generator.GenerateKeyPair();
```

which is fine, problem starts when I want to access the public key, `keyPair.Public`. This gives me an `IPublicKey` interface. On java, you will just cast it to `ECPublicKey` and on Xamarin you just can't do it.

I also noticed there is a missing member - the importat one for me - `getW()`- on xamarin representation of `ECPublicKey` vs java `ECPublicKey`.

[xamarin ECPublicKey](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Security.Interfaces.ECPublicKey/)

[java ECPublicKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/interfaces/ECPublicKey.html)

My question is - how to access - and cast the public key to ECPublicKey in Xamarin? I want to access the X and Y coordinates.

Is there a way to add this missing declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting to `ECPublicKey`, cast it to `ECPublicKeySpec`. IE,

```
var pubKeySpec = (Java.Security.Spec.ECPublicKeySpec)keyPair.Public;
var w = pubKeySpec.GetW();
```

Comment: Hi, I ended up with : Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue, except in my case I was already trying to cast it to [IECPublicKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.security.interfaces.iecpublickey?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) (as suggested in the deprecation message for [ECPublicKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.security.interfaces.ecpublickey?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12)). I kept getting an `InvalidCastException`, even though this is seemingly the correct way to do it in native Java/Android. I also got the same exception when trying to cast it to `ECPublicKeySpec` instead as suggested in the other answer here.

After a lot of searching and not finding anything relevant except this question, I've now found one method which works (adapted from [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/923edf27-03e3-4a26-b013-da450fc64651/elliptic-curve-cryptography?forum=xamarinios)), but I'm not sure why it's necessary to do it this way.

```csharp
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.GetInstance(KeyProperties.KeyAlgorithmEc);
ECPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = (ECPublicKeySpec)keyFactory.GetKeySpec(keyPair.Public, Java.Lang.Class.ForName("java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec"));
```

You can then use `publicKeySpec.GetW()` to access the coordindates.